# Ayuda, Error a la hora de abrir mi Excel en la nube - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola estoy trabajando en una reporte de excel pero cuando ejecuto en mi local se puede descargar y abrir normal sin ningun problema enonces lo subo a la nube y me sale esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo 
gracias

```
public function reporte_excel_total($lista) {

    set_time_limit(0);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $hoja = $this->excel->getActiveSheet();
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $hoja->setTitle('REPORTE');
    $hoja->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE SEMÁFORO ESCUELA  TOTAL');
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(24);
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $hoja->mergeCells('A1:M1');
    $hoja->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


    $hoja->mergeCells("A2:A3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("B2:B3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("C2:C3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("D2:D3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("E2:E3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("F2:F3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("G2:G3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("H2:H3");
    $hoja->mergeCells("I2:I3");

    $hoja->setCellValue('A2', "COD. MODULAR");
    $hoja->setCellValue('B2', "I.E.");
    $hoja->setCellValue('C2', "DIRECTOR");
    $hoja->setCellValue('D2', "RED");
    $hoja->setCellValue('E2', "DISTRITO");
    $hoja->setCellValue('F2', "NIVEL");
    $hoja->setCellValue('G2', "FECHA REGISTRO");
    $hoja->setCellValue('H2', "FECHA");
    $hoja->setCellValue('I2', "TURNO");

    $hoja->mergeCells("J2:M2");
    $hoja->setCellValue('J2', "DOCENTES")->getStyle('J2')->getFont()->setSize(15)->setBold(true);
    $hoja->getStyle('J2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $hoja->setCellValue('J3', "TOTAL DOCENTES");
    $hoja->setCellValue('K3', "ASISTENTES");
    $hoja->setCellValue('J3', "FALTANTES");
    $hoja->setCellValue('M3', "%");

    $hoja->mergeCells("N2:Q2");
    $hoja->setCellValue('N2', "ALUMNOS")->getStyle('N2')->getFont()->setSize(15)->setBold(true);
    $hoja->getStyle('N2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $hoja->setCellValue('N3', "TOTAL ALUMNOS");
    $hoja->setCellValue('O3', "ASISTENTES");
    $hoja->setCellValue('P3', "FALTANTES");
    $hoja->setCellValue('Q3', "%");

    $hoja->setAutoFilter('A3:Q3');

    $hoja->getStyle('A2:Q3')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('BDD7EE');
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('N')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('O')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('P')->setAutoSize(true);
    $hoja->getColumnDimension('Q')->setAutoSize(true);

    $cont = 4;
    foreach ($lista as $obj) {

        $porc_docente = null;
        $porc_alumno = null;

        if ($obj->opcion_1 > 0) {
            $porc_docente = round(($obj->opcion_2 / $obj->opcion_1) * 100, 2);
            $this->color_celda($porc_docente, 'K', 'K', $cont, $hoja);
        }

        if ($obj->opcion_3 > 0) {
            $porc_alumno = round(($obj->opcion_4 / $obj->opcion_3) * 100, 2);
            $this->color_celda($porc_alumno, 'O', 'O', $cont, $hoja);
        }

        $hoja->setCellValueExplicit('A' . $cont, $obj->codigoModular, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $hoja->getStyle('B' . $cont)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
        $hoja->setCellValueExplicit('B' . $cont, $obj->ie, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        $hoja->setCellValue('C' . $cont, $obj->director);
        $hoja->setCellValue('D' . $cont, $obj->red);
        $hoja->setCellValue('E' . $cont, $obj->distrito);
        $hoja->setCellValue('F' . $cont, $obj->nivel);
        $hoja->setCellValue('G' . $cont, $obj->fechaRegistro);
        $hoja->setCellValue('H' . $cont, $obj->fecha);
        $hoja->setCellValue('I' . $cont, $obj->turno);
        $hoja->setCellValue('J' . $cont, $obj->opcion_1);
        $hoja->setCellValue('K' . $cont, $obj->opcion_2);
        $hoja->setCellValue('L' . $cont, $obj->docentes_faltantes);
        $hoja->setCellValue('M' . $cont, $porc_docente);
        $hoja->setCellValue('N' . $cont, $obj->opcion_3);
        $hoja->setCellValue('O' . $cont, $obj->opcion_4);
        $hoja->setCellValue('P' . $cont, $obj->alumnos_faltantes);
        $hoja->setCellValue('Q' . $cont, $porc_alumno);


        $cont ++;
    }

    $filename = 'REPORTE_SEMÁFORO_ESCUELA_TOTAL.xls';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Comment: Hola si estas usando phpexcel por que no la genera xlsx. me ha sucedido que me produce ese error cuando trato de generar el xls con ese librería si gusta te digo como  es para cambiarla a xlsx.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez lo curioso esque en mi local si lo importa bien el problema es cuando lo subo a la nube, pero si tienes alguna solucion bienvenido sea

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo como es para la generación de ***xlsx*** espero que te sea de utilidad. Lo otro que puedes ver el el tipo de ***charset*** que estas usando, n puede ser diferente el de base de datos al ***script***.

```
public function reporte_excel_total($lista) {

set_time_limit(0);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$this->load->library('excel');
$hoja = $this->excel->getActiveSheet();
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$hoja->setTitle('REPORTE');
$hoja->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE SEMÁFORO ESCUELA  TOTAL');
$hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(24);
$hoja->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$hoja->mergeCells('A1:M1');
$hoja->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


$hoja->mergeCells("A2:A3");
$hoja->mergeCells("B2:B3");
$hoja->mergeCells("C2:C3");
$hoja->mergeCells("D2:D3");
$hoja->mergeCells("E2:E3");
$hoja->mergeCells("F2:F3");
$hoja->mergeCells("G2:G3");
$hoja->mergeCells("H2:H3");
$hoja->mergeCells("I2:I3");

$hoja->setCellValue('A2', "COD. MODULAR");
$hoja->setCellValue('B2', "I.E.");
$hoja->setCellValue('C2', "DIRECTOR");
$hoja->setCellValue('D2', "RED");
$hoja->setCellValue('E2', "DISTRITO");
$hoja->setCellValue('F2', "NIVEL");
$hoja->setCellValue('G2', "FECHA REGISTRO");
$hoja->setCellValue('H2', "FECHA");
$hoja->setCellValue('I2', "TURNO");

$hoja->mergeCells("J2:M2");
$hoja->setCellValue('J2', "DOCENTES")->getStyle('J2')->getFont()->setSize(15)->setBold(true);
$hoja->getStyle('J2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$hoja->setCellValue('J3', "TOTAL DOCENTES");
$hoja->setCellValue('K3', "ASISTENTES");
$hoja->setCellValue('J3', "FALTANTES");
$hoja->setCellValue('M3', "%");

$hoja->mergeCells("N2:Q2");
$hoja->setCellValue('N2', "ALUMNOS")->getStyle('N2')->getFont()->setSize(15)->setBold(true);
$hoja->getStyle('N2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$hoja->setCellValue('N3', "TOTAL ALUMNOS");
$hoja->setCellValue('O3', "ASISTENTES");
$hoja->setCellValue('P3', "FALTANTES");
$hoja->setCellValue('Q3', "%");

$hoja->setAutoFilter('A3:Q3');

$hoja->getStyle('A2:Q3')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setRGB('BDD7EE');
$hoja->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('N')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('O')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('P')->setAutoSize(true);
$hoja->getColumnDimension('Q')->setAutoSize(true);

$cont = 4;
foreach ($lista as $obj) {

    $porc_docente = null;
    $porc_alumno = null;

    if ($obj->opcion_1 > 0) {
        $porc_docente = round(($obj->opcion_2 / $obj->opcion_1) * 100, 2);
        $this->color_celda($porc_docente, 'K', 'K', $cont, $hoja);
    }

    if ($obj->opcion_3 > 0) {
        $porc_alumno = round(($obj->opcion_4 / $obj->opcion_3) * 100, 2);
        $this->color_celda($porc_alumno, 'O', 'O', $cont, $hoja);
    }

    $hoja->setCellValueExplicit('A' . $cont, $obj->codigoModular, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $hoja->getStyle('B' . $cont)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
    $hoja->setCellValueExplicit('B' . $cont, $obj->ie, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $hoja->setCellValue('C' . $cont, $obj->director);
    $hoja->setCellValue('D' . $cont, $obj->red);
    $hoja->setCellValue('E' . $cont, $obj->distrito);
    $hoja->setCellValue('F' . $cont, $obj->nivel);
    $hoja->setCellValue('G' . $cont, $obj->fechaRegistro);
    $hoja->setCellValue('H' . $cont, $obj->fecha);
    $hoja->setCellValue('I' . $cont, $obj->turno);
    $hoja->setCellValue('J' . $cont, $obj->opcion_1);
    $hoja->setCellValue('K' . $cont, $obj->opcion_2);
    $hoja->setCellValue('L' . $cont, $obj->docentes_faltantes);
    $hoja->setCellValue('M' . $cont, $porc_docente);
    $hoja->setCellValue('N' . $cont, $obj->opcion_3);
    $hoja->setCellValue('O' . $cont, $obj->opcion_4);
    $hoja->setCellValue('P' . $cont, $obj->alumnos_faltantes);
    $hoja->setCellValue('Q' . $cont, $porc_alumno);


    $cont ++;
}

    // Renombrar Hoja
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reporte');

    // Establecer la hoja activa, para que cuando se abra el documento se muestre primero.
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Se modifican los encabezados del HTTP para indicar que se envía un archivo de Excel.
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="reporte.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

}

Comment: En mi local corre al 100 pero cuando lo pongo en la nube me sale el error de arriba

Comment: Verifica que los dos configuraciones de php sean iguales eso lo puedes ver con el método **phpinfo** ejecuta uno en el local y el otro en el servidor y compáralo  a ver si existe alguna diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que en producción haya algún cambio que te esté generando un mensaje de advertencia en el navegador, en cuyo caso habría que volcar el mensaje en algún sitio para poder consultarlo:

```
public function reporte_excel_total($lista) {
    /* A partir de ahora cualquier salida al navegador se guardará en un buffer */
    ob_start();
    /* Obtenemos el listado de locales disponibles en el sistema */
    file_put_contents('log.txt', shell_exec('locale -a'), FILE_APPEND);

    set_time_limit(0);
    /* Damos más opciones, en el log aparecerán los disponibles */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES', 'es');
    $this->load->library('excel');


    /*****
      EL RESTO DE TU CÓDIGO
      (lo omito por claridad)
    *****/


    $filename = 'REPORTE_SEMÁFORO_ESCUELA_TOTAL.xls';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');

    /* Obtenemos el contenido del buffer y lo guardamos */
    file_put_contents('log.txt', ob_get_contents(), FILE_APPEND);
    /* Borramos el contenido que iba a ser enviado al navegador antes que el excel */
    ob_end_clean();

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Lo que hago es:

- Ejecuto un `locales -a` para volcar al archivo `log.txt` las locales disponibles. OJO: Sólo funciona en máquinas Linux (los servidores VPS "de la nube" suelen ser Linux).
- Retengo cualquier mensaje de advertencia generado en un buffer sin enviar al navegador.
- Agrego toda la información retenida al archivo `log.txt` para su posterior revisión y depuración.
- Por último limpio cualquier mensaje previo finalizando el almacenamiento en el buffer para que se genere el excel como es habitual.

Cuando compruebes si se genera correctamente el excel consulta el contenido del archivo `log.txt` que se habrá generado en tu servidor. Si no se ha generado ha sido, probablemente, porque necesites dar permisos de escritura al directorio.